# EC2 Instance cannot be accessed publicly

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ubuntu-14.04

I have configured EC2 instance(Ubuntu 14.04) on AWS. Intalled JDK, Tomcat,MySQL to deploy my web-application. After deploying, I can access it using localhost or Public IP(Provided by AWS) from UBUNUTU (inside the ubuntu) but can not access from outside. I want to access it publicly. How to do that?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming, and is a question for Server Fault.

Comment: I disabled the SELinux protection and disabled the Ubuntu firewall but still i cant access it from outside ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the Security group Setting for the port 80 (HTTP) is allowed for 0.0.0.0/0 [ all internet ].

The other items which might come in the way of public access are

1. Attachment of Elastic IP
2. Attachment of Internet gateway to VPC
3. 0.0.0.0/0 rule to subnet route table
4. ACL Rules
5. operating system firewall

Comment: Elastic IP is not being shown under my instance. So I think I am not assigned with it.(I dont know). Opertaing system firewall is configured and its disabled at the moment. Please can you elaborate point number 2,3,4

Comment: Attach Elastic IP and try again

Comment: Thanks Naveen, Its working. I configured Security Groups, as it was not allowing inbound traffic from outside network.